# update source code of locally installed pip package

Tags: python, pip

I installed my package with `pip install -e .`
If I now change something in the source code, do I need to run `pip install -e .` again or will it consider the updated source files when I run the program?
Thanks for your help!
Tamme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to reinstall the package. That's what the editable install (mentioned by the `-e` option) does; instead of installing the package to site, it only puts a link to the source files.

However if you modify the package metadata (things like author's name, description, version etc. the stuff found in `setup.cfg` or `setup.py`) that wouldn't be carried over, for that change to reflect you need to reinstall the package.